# Best way to craft an AnyCPU assembly using either 32-bit or 64-bit native DLLs?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, .net-assembly

I generated bindings for a native library but realized that imports differ between 32-bit and 64-bit.

#### Problem:

Not only the entry point differ, but also the calling convention:

32-bit import:

```
[DllImport("implot", EntryPoint = "??0ImPlotPoint@@QAE@XZ", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.ThisCall)]
```

64-bit import:

```
[DllImport("implot", EntryPoint = "??0ImPlotPoint@@QEAA@XZ", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

Since these are compile-time constants, there's no way to have an `if (64bit) then ... else ...` for these imports.

#### What I've been thinking about:

**Using ordinals instead of decorated names as entry points:**

That won't work because they don't necessarily point to the same export.

**Defer stuff to two inner classes, e.g. NativeMethods32, NativeMethods64:**

One would have to put bit-ness checks everywhere to dispatch to the right class, tedious as well.

**Generate two inner managed assemblies, one 32-bit, one 64-bit:**

Have the AnyCPU assembly dynamically load the appropriate managed assembly at runtime.

#### Question:

Is there an effective, proven pattern to tackle such problem?

Comment: Give different names to the two C# import functions, and have a 3rd function that will call one or the other, similar to this (but with same dll name): https://stackoverflow.com/a/23216851/403671

Comment: The best way to handle this is not to. Stick to 64 bit.

Comment: @SimonMourier This is easy but that check at every call is just silly in terms of performance.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I could, my project is 64-bit ready, but having 32-bit support would be nice too.

Comment: No, in release, in most cases the JIT compiler will get rid of the test (it knows it's running x64 or not) and tail call to the corresponding import https://i.imgur.com/HQIlPAY.png

Comment: Nobody should recommend pinvoking C++ class member functions.  Best to take the approach shown [here](https://github.com/goatcorp/ImGui.NET/tree/930d9067653c3ea6e7992255a69170ecadcde144), relying on a C wrapper for this C++ library.

Comment: @SimonMourier That's an interesting piece of information!

Comment: @HansPassant While I agree with you on that one, generated stuff with that library is schizophrenic: different vector classes for value types and reference types, additional classes with a `Ptr` suffix, zero XML documentation... My bindings do address all that and are more user friendly, at the expense of what you've mentioned of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem rewriting the entire stuff with Roslyn to produce an AnyCPU module.

Like so:

```
public class Whatever
{
    internal partial struct __Internal
    {
        // keep fields
        // remove methods
    }

    internal partial struct __Internal32
    {
        // remove fields
        // insert 32-bit methods
    }
    
    internal partial struct __Internal64
    {
        // remove fields
        // insert 64-bit methods
    }
    
    public static void Test()
    {
        if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
        {
            __Internal32.Test();
        }
        else
        {
            __Internal64.Test();
        }
    }
}
```

The result works very well, the platform target can be switched as usual and it just works.

Comment: Using `Environment.Is64BitProcess` is arguably a bit cleaner ([and still JIT-optimizable](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgHgbALANALiAhgZwLYB8ACAmAjAWAChMBmAAhzIGEyBvIsxi8zKMgWQAoBKOhpgQEsAZmU4BRAHYA3QQCcA9pNQBTSXAB0ASWTQAQoLgAFRQGMVyZL3qEBdpplwBOTgAYwpxMJXBEwFQAy3ADc/PYAvowqADbIKny29naOLu4AJiqIaf4qwkGhiRFhZOFE4UA)).

Comment: Definitely makes sense, I will upgrade my code rewriter to do so, thank you :)

Comment: OP: I know in a way it's a hack... but it's an _elegant_ hack! Nice work!

Comment: @Spike0xff Another life saving hack when it comes to marshalling some tricky stuff turned out to be the invaluable `Span<T>`. :) You can see a monster assembly rewritten this way here: https://github.com/aybe/DearImGui. The main class is 20K+ LOC of generated code but it just works.